# What is the proper or recommended way to save String[]'s, Array's, ArrayList's and int[]'s to Android?

Tags: java, android, data, array

I've looked up this question many many times but keep seeing different answers, what is the BEST way to save array's? It seems ludicrously infantile that there is no standard or easy way to save arrays like you would save a String or Int... How should this be done? As I understand, putting to much information into SharedPreferences is not a good practise so please do not suggest this method. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have three options for storage on an Android device:

**Shared Preferences**
Shared Preferences is a Key/Value store, intended to store a small amount of *settings* type data.  It supports primitive types like strings and numbers, stored in an XML format.  Shared Preferences are available throughout the application, and they persist between sessions.

**File Storage**
File storage can be used for what you would expect file storage to normally be used for: any arbitrary data.  You can serialize and deserialize objects to a file and store structured data of arbitrary complexity, including dictionaries and other types of collections.

**SQLite Database**
Use this when you want more sophisticated and structured data storage, i.e. anywhere you would need a relational database.

In general, if you're simply persisting a dictionary, array or other collection, the best way to do that is to serialize it to a file.

Comment: Would you recommend SQLite or File Storage for an arraylist of roughly 50 entries?

Comment: That would probably fit quite easily in Shared Preferences, if you're storing primitive types.  You haven't really said much about your application, though, so it's difficult to make a determination.

Comment: I'm saving around 20 strings in an array. Is there anyway to save these strings in an array without the overly complicated string splitter and commas?

Comment: What overly complicated string splitter and commas?  Make a loop, and save each array item individually.